# Get a list of all the items based on the latest entry

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this collection of data shaped like this:

```
public class PriceList
{
    [Display(Name = "Price List ID")]
    public int m_ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Price List Provider")]
    public int m_Provider { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Current Book")]
    public int m_BookID { get; set; }

    public BookInfo m_Book { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Price")]
    public decimal m_Price { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date of price list")]
    public DateTime m_PriceListDate { get; set; }
}
```

A Price list is a price list object created when I get a price for a particular item in my mvc-app. It can be created many times over a same day, week, month, or year.

So now a book can be part of a category, for example "Comic book". And my problem is that I am trying to create a method that will give me only the LATEST entry, so the most recent date only, of all items based on this collection.

Here's the method:

```
    public List<PriceList> ListLatestPriceListByBookCategoryID(int _id)
    {
        List<PriceList> listToReturn = new List<PriceList>();

        var priceListQry = from pl in m_Db.PriceList
                           where pl.Book.BookCatID == _id
                           // INSERT CODE HERE???
                           select pl;

        if (!priceListQry.Any())
        {
            return null;
        }

        listToReturn.AddRange(priceListQry);

        return listToReturn;
    }
```

Basically, I want to created a query that will return only the needed data. And this needed data consist of only the most recent entry of each book found by the id. I can have many category and many books.

Can anyone help me out figure a good way to do this? Up to now all I've though about was a massive method that would iterate through the whole list to filter all unnecessary data, but I'd like something more efficient because I will eventually have a mass of data and this will prove to take a lot of time.

*** EDIT ***

As of now I have added this line of code:

```
var result = m_Db.PriceList.GroupBy(r => r.BookID).Select(r => new
                {
                    BookID = r.OrderByDescending(t => t.PriceListDate).First().BookID,
                    PriceListDate = r.OrderByDescending(t => t.PriceListDate).First().PriceListDate
                });
```

And I have no error on this line of code and it makes sense to me. However, the `listToReturn.AddRange(result)` line now throw this error:

`Error  13  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.Entities.PriceList>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
var result = m_Db.PriceList.GroupBy(r => r.m_BookID)
                 .Select(r=> new 
                 { 
                     BookID = r.OrderByDescending(t=> t.m_PriceListDate).First().m_BookID,
                     Date = r.OrderByDescending(t=> t.m_PriceListDate).First().m_PriceListDate,
                 });
```

*(Not really sure how much efficient that would be)*

Comment: Two questions: the list.GroupBy is what, exactly? And would you call this method through the query, or after?

Comment: @HerveS, `GroupBy` as the name suggest will group the list based on the BookID, then from that group you will select the first record based on Order of latest date. You can execute that query on DB end as well, but it may need some improvements in performance. See the generate SQL and you would be able to understand it better.

Comment: Ok, I will try this around. the `list.` is a variable?

Comment: @HerveS, its just a dummy variable you can replace it with `m_Db.PriceList`

Comment: I've been wondering: is the `.Select(r => new` line creating a new object? And, if so, must I initialize all the fields of the objects when I do so? That might explain the error.

Comment: @HerveS, the error you are getting is because the result is selecting objects of anonymous type, whereas you are returning `List<PriceList>`, there are couple of ways of doing that. First you can project to your own class with two properites ID and Date, or you can query your existing list and compare them against the group ids from the 2nd list, and then return the pricelist. But You said in your post that you only needed minimum data, in that case its better if you create your own class and project your result set to that.

Comment: @HerveS, you are right, **but you can't project** to existing type provided by the entity framework. You have to create your own class to hold temporary results, and return that.

Comment: A last question: in the line of code that you provided me, how could I make sure that the books I receive belongs to the BookCatID provided in the method up there?

Comment: Add that before the GroupBy clause `.Where(r=> r.m_BookID == _Id)`, But I don't see `BookCatID` field in your class.

Comment: The field is a field of the m_Book object field. So I have tried `.Where(r => r.m_Book.m_BookCatId == _id)` and it works.